# add dynamic image into UIView at UITableview's headerview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I have a UIView above the tableview cells. There are UIImageView and UILabels.

What I expect is that the UIImageView and UILabels can get data from networking request.

May I know where can I reference UIImageView and UILabels, where should I write logic code(api calls)

[image]

Here is my view structure

[image]

Comment: This `IBOutlet`s and code is usually in your `UITableViewController` subclass.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create IBOutlet of UIImageview and UILabel in MainTableViewcontroller and initiates networking request in viewcontroller's viewDidAppear() method.Update UI on main thread once response received.